# How to draw a horizontal line on right side of Label vertical centred

Tags: css, styles, line, grouping

Can I do such a thing with CSS?

I had an Idea with text-decoration , but it is always problem with text lenght. Can i do something like that with only one html element?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5NXA.png

Comment: See this question's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909888/how-would-you-design-the-html-markup-for-this/8909962#8909962

Answer (score 3):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909888/how-would-you-design-the-html-markup-for-this/8909962#8909962) applied to your question:

```css
#line{
  border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
  overflow:visible;
  height:9px;        
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}
#line span{
  background-color: white;        
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="line"><span>TEXT</span></div>
```

Comment: super idea, i have to only force smartgwt to generate such html:)

Answer (score 1):

**Look Here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/LRSuJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

It ain't too pretty but http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/34bBd/

Uses one element, doesn't rely on hard-coded numbers, perfectly reusable.

Comment: Hey, great answer. Is it possible, though, to add padding to the right of the word, so that the line begins after some whitespace?

Comment: I played with the proposal and came to the following improvement: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyganchev/d90g1b87/1/. This version eliminates the need for `overflow-x` control and any fiddling with `position`

Comment: one more refinement to ensure flex does not word wrap the label which is usually not the expected behavior anyway - https://jsfiddle.net/tonyganchev/d90g1b87/11/ . Looking forward to anybody solving the problem more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **fieldset with legend** tag. and remove those lines you might not need. like left right and button. (or make the color white or transparent)